# What do these symbols mean ??= in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I find this in some class and am not sure what they do
`??` , `??=`

example :

```
cursorColor ??= selectionTheme.cursorColor ?? cupertinoTheme.primaryColor;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`??` is used to provide default value for null cases.

```dart
int? a ;

int b = a?? 0;// it a is null b will get 0
```

> `b ??= value;` Assign value to b if b is null; otherwise, b stays the same

`cursorColor ??= selectionTheme.cursorColor ?? cupertinoTheme.primaryColor;`

If `cursorColor` value is null, then it will use right part.

If it finds `selectionTheme.cursorColor` is equal to null, then it will return `cupertinoTheme.primaryColor`.

Comment: More about [assignment-operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assignment-operators)

Answer (score 2):

Those are Null-aware operators.

let's say we have an `int`, and base on that we're going to complete our example, which it is like below:

```
int? item; // this one is currently null, since there's no value defined as default.
item ??= 10; // here we check if `item` is null define new value for `item`.
print(item); // and here, base on above codes, we should get 10 because in above code
// we've checked our `item` if it's not null, define a new value.
```

now base on above example, we can do:

```
item ??=5; // in this case, since item is not null, and we've a value for `item` 
// already, we should get 10.
print(item); // 10 will be print since in second operator checked null value for variable
// and in this case value wasn't null this time.
```

And another one `??` in this case is going to return value in left of operator in case left side of operator is not null, for example :

```
print(10 ?? 15); // this will return 10, because left side of operator isn't null.
print(null ?? 20); // this one will return 20, because left side of operator is null.
```

So base on your code, if we split your code in 2 part, your code is checking if `cursorColor` is null, it will try to return a new value base on second part of your code, which at that part, It will check for another null value.